# How to extract Parent.Parent field value from SOQL Query?

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

This is my query

```
SOBject acc = [Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Account.Parent.Parent.Name, Name from Contacts__r) from Sales_Location__c where Id ='a005j000009xxxBAxU'];
Contact abc =(Contact)(acc.getSobjects('Contacts__r')).get(0);
System.debug(abc.get('Account.Parent.Parent.Name'));
```

But instead of using get() if I  directly use abc.Account.Parent.Parent.Name, I am getting result. But I don't know why  my code fails in case of get().  In Actual scenario abc is of SObject type that's why I need to use get() here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sObject.get()` works on only 1 field, it will not travel via "dots". See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24804/799 (shameless plug, it's my own answer)

You can try like that

```
Sales_Location__c location = [Select Id, Name, 
    (Select Id, Account.Parent.Parent.Name, Name from Contacts__r)
    from Sales_Location__c 
    where Id ='a005j000009xxxBAxU'];

if(!location.Contacts__r.isEmpty()){
    Contact abc = location.Contacts__r[0];
    if(abc.Account != null && abc.Account.Parent != null && abc.Account.Parent.Parent != null){
        System.debug(abc.Account.Parent.Parent.Name);
    } else {
        System.debug('there is no grandparent account');
    }
}
```

but this null checking gets very annoying after a while. There's a fairly recent addition https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm

```
// the query is stupid, the parent name will always be null
// but my point is it's accessed safely, it won't throw the
// null reference exception
Contact c = [SELECT Account.Parent.Name 
    FROM Contact 
    WHERE Account.ParentId = null
    LIMIT 1];
System.debug(c.Account?.Parent?.Name);
```

P.S. even if your function receives a generic sObject - you can always try to cast it back to the original

`Sales_Location__c loc = (Sales_Location__c) abc;`

So it'll give you simpler code later on, compile-time checks... Don't suffer with generic sobjects if you don't have to. Check [`instanceof`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_instanceof.htm) too if your function can accept sobjects from multiple sources

Comment: Actually I am getting all these field dynamically in String format So I think using dot way  ( like this "c.Account?.Parent?.Name") is not a option for me.

Comment: If you need to stay on the generic sobjects realm you'll need to 'your.dotted.field.path.name'.split('.') and call getsobject with every token except last one.